# Cant get background changing images centered

Tags: html, css

I have been strugglign for the last few horus trying to make it so that the background class will be centered in the website, but i have absolute position and fixed in my css for the inside of it because i need it done for a changing fading background image. But my problem is i cant get it centered in the site for example see in div.background i have margin 0 and it still isnt centered it just stays to the left i even tried  but it doesnt work... How cani  get the background div i made to be centered...

```
<div class="background">
<img src="images/back_1.jpg" width="990" height="660" alt="pic1" />
<img src="images/back_2.jpg" width="990" height="660" alt="pic2" />
<img src="images/back_3.jpg" width="990" height="660" alt="pic3" />
</div>
```

style

```
  div.background {
      margin:auto;
      width: 990px;
      position:absolute; 
      left:0px;
      top:0px;
      z-index:-1;
  }
  div.background img {
      position:fixed; 
      list-style: none;
      left:0px;
      top:0px;
  }
  div.background ul li.show {
      z-index:500
  }
```

Comment: I think it's a bit confusing that you are using the 'foreground' img-tag, but consider it as a background image at the same time...what's the issue with that ?

Comment: It pays to spend time working on grammar and spelling issues.  I'm unclear as to exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  However, in a situation where you are using absolute positioning, margin:auto is essentially meaningless (because it's removed from the usual document flow, which means it's margins won't effect anything else).  What you are saying with your declarations is "I want this at the top left of the first node with position:relative assigned" -- which is rarely, if ever, going to be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
div.background img {
    position: fixed; 
    list-style: none;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -495px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

`left: 50%` moves the left edge of the `img` to the center of the page, then `margin-left: -495px;` shifts it back to the left exactly the right amount so that it's centered.

Comment: Wow that is a weird trick i never ever sseen a way of doing it like that? Why is it that i need to margin left it so far?

Comment: It's `-(width of the image / 2)px`.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work. What you should have is something like:

```
div.background {
    position: absolute
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: no-repeat center center url('images/back_1.jpg');
}
```

and eliminate the individual `<img>` tags inside the div.

You can then use some javascript to swap the background images whenever, since CSS1 only allows a single background image (CSS3 allows multiples).

Comment: I guess he's using `img`s because he wants to fade between the images, which can't be done with a `background`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
#background {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 990px;
  position:absolute; 
  top:0px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```